# How to create lock pattern without pin in Android 6

Tags: lock-screens

When I'm trying to secure my phone with the pattern it is forcing me to create a pin which isn't secure. Is there any way to bypass pin creation screen?

Comment: Which model and Android version is it?

Comment: lg g5 with 6.0.1

Comment: This is a "feature" in your LG G5's software. The only way to change it were to download a stock android ROM or use an Xposed module.